# ComplexHeatmap Maximum Height of Row Labels anno_mark

Tags: r, heatmap, seurat, complexheatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap of my cluster marker genes using ComplexHeatmap. However, I have way too many genes and I only want to show certain ones, so I found out that I have to use `anno_mark()` within the `rowAnnotation()` function. However, I still have lot of genes that I want to show and when I do this, the row annotations overflow the heatmap.

I tried changing the font size of the row annotations, but this just decreases the text size without changing the annotation marks. I also tried adding `extend = unit(0, "mm")` to make sure it's not extending the row annotations past the heatmap, but that didn't work. Then I tried adding the `link_height = unit(0, "mm")` parameter to anno_mark, but that didn't change the output either.

```
nlmegadegmat <- nlmeganoNA.small@assays$RNA@scale.data[nlmega.markers_res0.8$gene, ]

nlmeglevel <- unique(nlmeganoNA$RNA_snn_res.0.8) %>% sort()

cluster_anno <- factor(nlmeganoNA.small$RNA_snn_res.0.8, levels = nlmeglevel)

myCol <- colorRampPalette(c('dodgerblue', 'black', 'yellow'))(50)
myBreaks <- seq(-2, 2, length.out = 50)

nlmegShowGenes <- nlmega.markers_res0.8$gene[c(1,2,3,11,12,14,16,22,25,28,32,36,37,40,
41,44,47,51,52,53,61,63,65,69,71,72,74,81,82,86,90,91,95,96,99,101,102,104,111,113,114,
118,121,124,131,132,134,137,141,143,144,150,151,156,158,161,163,166,167,168,171,173,181,
183,186,191,192,195,202,203,209,211,213,218,219,225,227,240,241,244,248,251,254,259,265,
267,271,273,275)]

nlmegHAright = rowAnnotation(foo = anno_mark(at = which(rownames(nlmegadegmat) %in% nlmegShowGenes),
                                     labels = rownames(nlmegadegmat[rownames(nlmegadegmat)%in%nlmegShowGenes],
                                     labels_gp = gpar(fontsize=2),
                                     extend = unit(0, "mm"),
                                     link_height = link_width))

Heatmap(nlmegadegmat, name = "Expression",  
        column_split = cluster_anno,
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
        show_column_dend = FALSE,
        cluster_column_slices = TRUE,
        column_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
        column_gap = unit(0.5, "mm"),
        cluster_rows = FALSE,
        show_row_dend = FALSE,
        col = colorRamp2(myBreaks, myCol),
        row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6),
        column_title_rot = 90,
        top_annotation = HeatmapAnnotation(foo = anno_block(gp = gpar(fill = scales::hue_pal()(28)))),
        right_annotation = nlmegHAright,
        show_column_names = FALSE,
        use_raster = TRUE)
```

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so here is the solution, although this post is old, in case anyone else is interested:

https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap/reference/anno_mark.html

You could probably set something like:

```
nlmegHAright = rowAnnotation(foo = anno_mark(at = which(rownames(nlmegadegmat) %in% nlmegShowGenes),
labels = rownames(nlmegadegmat[rownames(nlmegadegmat)%in%nlmegShowGenes],
  labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 4),
  extend = unit(10, "mm"),
  lines_gp = gpar(),
  padding = -0.5,
  link_width = unit(5, "mm"), 
  link_height = unit(5, "mm"))
```